# How can I add JLabel with background image in loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, jlabel, imageicon

I need to make room JLabel with background.  This background it's state of room 
just I want way to change this colors to images in loop
I make a hotel booking room and some other service and I don't know how to do this

```
private void checkstatus() {
    jPanel2.removeAll();
    int dx = 1; 
    ResultSet Rroom;
    Rroom = DB.RunQuery("Select * From rooms");

    final ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("c://Des.jpg");

    try {
        while(Rroom.next()) {
            String Rstatus = Rroom.getString(3);
            rou+=40;

            Label xlabel;
            xlabel = new Label("Label 1",Label.CENTER);
            Font bigFont = new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 11);
            xlabel.setFont(bigFont);

            if(Rstatus.equals("Busy"))
                xlabel.setBackground(Color.red);
            else if (Rstatus.equals("Test"))
                xlabel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            else
                xlabel.setBackground(Color.green);

            jPanel2.add(xlabel);
            xlabel.setForeground(Color.black);
            xlabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(rou, rou2, 35, 35));
            xlabel.setText("1");

            if(rou==365) {
                rou=-35;
                // El 2rtfa3
                rou2 +=40;
            }

            dx++; 
        }  // end of loop

        rou = -35; // for new check
        rou2=10; // for new check   

    }// try 
    catch (SQLException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post code, please make sure that it is correctly indented with consistant formatting! This just makes it easier for us to read it, and therefore help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a JLabel with an icon, you should use [JLabel#setIcon(Icon)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29).

```
xlabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(yourImage));
```

Comment: Error(635,19):  cannot find method setIcon(javax.swing.ImageIcon)

Comment: After looking at your code again, I noticed you use a Label instead of JLabel.  I answered your question, which was in regards to JLabel.  Which are you actually using?  If you are in fact using java.awt.Label, that would be the cause of no setIcon method being present.  To add an image to a awt Label, you would need to do far more work, so I recommend using a JLabel if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
setIcon(Icon icon)
```

method of JLabel class.